# Checking random sample component identity in Julia

Tags: arrays, random, julia, sample

I have created a mixture of k=3 simple normal distributions in **Julia** as following (Distributions.jl):

```
mixm = MixtureModel(Normal[
     Normal(-2.0, 1.2),    
     Normal(0.0, 1.0),    
     Normal(2.0, 2.5)], 
     [0.2,0.5, 0.3])
```

And then I sampled using:

```
sample = rand(mixm, 10)
```

So we get 10 samples belonging to an of the 3 normals. This is a 10-element array. **How can I find which component each element comes from?**

I assume this must be easy since Julia randomly chooses one of the two normals to sample element i in the array `sample`.

I want to exploint an `if` loop so that I store the elements of each component to two separate lists.

Comment: "I assume this must be easy..." Statistics in a nutshell. You cannot definitively say which one, but you can ask for the `loglikelihood` of it coming from a given component.

Comment: @Marion: Given you want to know which distribution a sample came from, could you just create three different normal distributions and sample from them separately rather than in a `MixtureModel`? If not, maybe you could clarify what you're hoping to do and why you need the `MixtureModel`?

Comment: @htl I did so after all, indeed. But (without knowing too much about Julia) I would assume that since the samples are generated according to n distributions Julia specific "picks" each time a specific components and can remember it.